# Java Object send on Network

Tags: java

```
Details d = new Details(5425, "Vosu Mittal/CN");

ByteArrayOutputStream byteoutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream objectoutputstream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteoutputStream);

objectoutputstream.writeObject(d);     
sendData = byteoutputStream.toByteArray(); 

DatagramPacket sendpacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, internetAddress, port);
socket.send(sendpacket);
```

Server Side Code is

```
receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
socket.receive(receivePacket);
System.out.print("Connected to Server");
InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
int port = receivePacket.getPort();
int packetsize = receivePacket.getLength();
byte[] bytecount = receivePacket.getData();

ByteArrayInputStream byteinputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytecount);
ObjectInputStream objectinputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteinputStream);

Details d = (Details)objectinputStream.readObject();
String data = new String(d.toString());

System.out.println("\t"+ data+ "\tIP Address is = "+ IPAddress+ "\tPort Address is ="+ port+ "\tByte Count is = "+ packetsize );
String reply = "Thank you for the message";
```

My class is defined as Follows with  Serializable Interface

```
int id;
String name;

private void showDetails(){
    System.out.println("Id:"+id);
    System.out.println("Name:"+name);
}
```

Still, I am not able to get them on the client side, rectify the code if required?

Comment: do you get any runtime errors? In my opinion you should make sure that __internet address__ and __port__ parameters are the same for the client and server.

Comment: No errors , program gets compiled but output is not printed here..